# Type of error in expression evaluating process

Tags: compiler-theory

Supposing I want to write module to evaluate e simple string expression like `"5+3"`, `"(7*8/2)/6"` etc...
The process that I am thinking of is:

1. Lexical analysis in order to convert the string to set of atoms (numbers and operation).
2. Convert the set of atoms from infix to postfix
3. Evaluate the postfix and output the final result

My question is about the errors that happens in each stage:

1. In first stage I should handle undefined symbols or empty string and calling them lexical errors. **Is that right? anything to add?**
2. In the second stage, having something like two consequence multiplications symbol (*) is a not valid thing. **What is this error called?**
3. In the third stage, Division by zero is an example of an error. **What are this kind of errors called?**

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Comment: (1) Sounds right, though they could be syntax errors too.  (2) Syntax error: valid syntax does not have `**` as a valid operator or sequence of operators.  (3) Run-time errors.

Comment: @melpomene Absolutely not, I have just started to be interested in compilers design and started to read some articles here and there. BTW, I have studied this subject in university and I am sure that I used to be able to answer this question but now I can remember almost nothing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, May you please make it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Lexical error sounds right, though they could be syntax errors too.
2. Syntax error: valid syntax does not have `**` as a valid operator or sequence of operators.
3. Run-time errors, or sometimes semantic errors.